# Authentification with REST API - simple way

Tags: php, rest, api, oauth

**What i want:**

Hi, I'm before a standard problem I want to make stateless rest api which will be secure for users. Dispite this I want to avoid big solution like Oauth which is a bit overkill for my small aplication

**What i want to avoid:**

As it is say in previous section I want to avoid using too big solution for small up because make it work will take me maybe even more then develop app it self.

I am also not sure if I want to try to write my own solution it self because I can easy forget on something. Or even dont't even think of something as I am not a security expert.

**How I think it may work easy:**

I believe part of this is how e.g. Oauth works however here is my points:

1. user send to `/api/login.php` server found that user credentials as correct
2. server generate some unique token and store it in table next to username, also send is back to user as response on his login request
3. on every request user send from now. Server as 1th thing checkif he get a token from a user and if token is one of tokens server created before.
4. alternativly after this it check for access (if user have permission for this function, or e.g for data with `id=xzy`)
5. if answer on 3 (or 4 as well) is true he make a real request which get data from a server
6. This unique token will stay in table for 1 day and all tokens will be deleted in night by some CRON script.
7. Also if user logout earlier his token will be deleted

**Advantages:**

- I think it's pretty easy to implement

**Disadvantages:**

- Not sure if it's secure to store tokens in table, also it may have affect on performance to always make request on DB
- Possible issue of user surfing website in the middle of the night (pretty low % but still...) it will not be nice if in the middle of surfing site will logout you and return `401`

**Question:**
What would be the best way to implement nice and secure restfull api without creating some big oauth server and client site?

Comment: First thing ensure you;re using SSH for all connections to your REST API. This doesn't guarantee security but goes along way to helping.

oAuth is often misunderstood, its generally only needed when giving a 3rd party access to your applications (or parts of it) its not needed for giving your own internal applications access.

Comment: Right I have frontend and backend. Anyone can take token from frontend application and use it anytime they want. Of course you can generate site by server not just give data and generate by JS. But this is not what i look for. I am frontend developer so I want simple backend and strong frontend :)